# In snort alert what does initial values "07/31-16:19:48.614462 [**] ...." mean?

Tags: snort

Can anyone please tell me what does initial values in a snort alert mean. E.g., what does "07/31-16:19:48.614462" mean in following alert

```
07/31-16:19:48.614462  [**] [1:86300000:1] 503 irc_bot_cmd ExampleRule XY .... [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 10.14.44.37:80 -> 169.254.100.26:49413
```

Comment: That looks like a timestamp: 31st July, at nearly 20 past 4 in the afternoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats the time and date of the alert in the fastalert output format: MONTH/DAY-HOUR:MIN:SEC.MILIIS